# C# Getting access to subclass variable while operating on superclass objects

Tags: c#, loops, inheritance

I am building a simple german learning helper program and one of its elements is a dictionary. To manage all the words, I've added three classes: `Noun`, `Adjective` and `Verb`. They all inherit from another abstract class `Word`. The noun class also contains an `Article` enum.
All the words (Adjective, Noun and Verb objects) are stored in a `List<Word>`.. I have trouble printing them in ListView columns or more specifically - getting access to the field I want.

Basically, I want to loop through all the words in the List. While doing this, check if current item is a noun (Noun type of object) - if so, get its article. If not, print "--" and then add the word translations to columns.

Here is the method:

```
private void UpdateList(List<Word> currentWordList) //passing the List
{
    wordsListView.Items.Clear();
    int index = 1; // first column of the number

    foreach (Word w in currentWordList)
    {
        ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem("" + index);
        if (w is Noun)
            newItem.SubItems.Add(w.Article); //here is the error (no definition for "Article")
        else
            newItem.SubItems.Add("--");

        newItem.SubItems.Add(w.GermanTranslation);
        newItem.SubItems.Add(w.PolishTranslation);

        wordsListView.Items.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Consider using data binding on your GUI elements. Override `ToString()` for the classes (like `Word` and its subclasses) which you want to hold in lists. Many things become much easier when the GUI elements actually *are* the actual data.

Comment: You're attempting to violate some fundamental principles of object oriented design.  The superclass shouldn't have any kind of dependency on a particular subclass.  If there's functionality that a subclass can implement which a superclass needs to invoke, make the functionality abstract and implement it in the subclasses.

Comment: @David Harsh words. Just how is the OP in your opinion trying to introduce an "dependency on a particular subclass" into the superclass? (The dependency/knowledge would be introduced in the GUI control code here, imo.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I thought this method was on the parent class.  Either way, it's still a violation.  If the `Word` object doesn't have the functionality desired, then the OP shouldn't be trying to cast to a sub-type.  This method accepts a collection of `Word` objects, so it should operate on exactly those.  If a methods needs `Noun` objects, it should accept `Noun` objects.  Liskov Substitution is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast `w` to `Noun` like this:

```
Noun noun = (Noun)w;
```

Then use the `noun` variable to access the `Article`.

Having said that, a better way to do it is to define an abstract method in `Word` called something like `GetDescription` that gets the description of the word.

Here is an example:

```
public abstract class Word
{
    public abstract string GetDescription();
    //....
}

public class Noun : Word
{
    public override string GetDescription()
    {
        //Here you can access the Article property
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Then in the loop, you can use the `GetDescription` method to get the description of each word.

Comment: You might reword the first statement to "You *could* cast, if you really want to..." since casting is definitely not what the OP "should" do.  The rest of this answer is what the OP *should* do :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
@David - why casting is something I should not do? I'm a rookie and if casting in this case is a bad practice, I'd love to learn why ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Dandry: Look up the "S.O.L.I.D." principles of object oriented design.  This is specifically related to the Liskov Substitution Principle.  In this case casting is "peeking under the hood" of the implementation details of an object rather than using only its exposed interface.  This creates tight coupling and makes code very difficult to maintain.  Casting has its uses, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad - I've been analyzing the second part of your post based on what David said and I wonder how could I make any use of GetDescription method. For now, I have `GermanTranslation`, `PolishTranslation` and  enum `WordType`  properties in `Word` abstract class, which all the subclasses inherit from. What would I have to put into this method you mentioned to actually be able to print these variables into three columns in ListView?

Comment: @Dandry, in your code you are looping though the words, and for each word, it seems you are creating a `ListViewItem`. It seems to me that in one of the columns, you want to put something that is related to the word. For nouns, you want to put the `Article`, and for other words, you are putting "--". What is the name of this column? what does it present? a description? What I was suggesting is that you create a method in your base class to obtain such value (that has a concept like description). And you can customize how this value is generated for each subclass.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad - the ListView contains four columns - first one is just a number (1, 2, 3 and so on), second one is an article column, third one is a `GermanTranslation` columns and last one is `PolishTranslation`. I am looking through words and get their properties - each property to each column. I'll think about the solution you mentioned, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast W to the Child Class. Like so

```
newItem.SubItems.Add(((Noun)w).Article)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!